# Setting conditional value in twig do something block

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to setting a conditional value using `if` and `else if` inside a twig template, so that is what I have to do

```
{% set x = '1' %}
{% if a and b %}
{% set x = '2' %}
{% elseif a or b  %}
{% set x = '3' %}
{% else %}
{% set x = '4' %}
{% endif %}
```

The above works fine for me. But my question is, is there a way I can achieve the same using only one `{% %}` (do something) block.

Something like:

```
{%
    set x = '1'
    if a and b
    ...
    elseif a or b
    ...
    else
%}
```

Comment: I think it's not possible, Twig is created as template engine, any logic should live outside templates. You can write `twig simple function` and use it like: `{% setClassBasedOnProvidedVariables(a,b) %}`

Comment: @malcolm is right, in Twig, all control structures are enclosed into `{%` / `%}` blocks separately, that's by design and can't be changed. Are you trying to achieve something specific? We may help you to choose the best way to go.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. Have the same if,else inside one `{%%}` block. Is that possible?